# a way to see my website as if on a ipad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

I've got a little problem with my website and ipad/iphones. A certain tag in my css causes problems and I'm unable to check if I've solved the problem. Is there a way to look at my website as if on an ipad while not actually buying an ipad. Is there something like an ipad emulator or something?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/ipad-testing-using-safari-browser-without-ipad

Answer (score 1):

You can use web (free) services that provide such functionality. There is a lot of them. For example: http://ipadpeek.com/ or http://mobiletest.me/.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple solution that doesn't require any further app installation.

If you're running google Chrome you can enter the developer tools by hitting F12 on a PC and Command+option+I on a Mac.

In the developer tools you have on the top left corner of the screen a mobile device emulator, which you can choose various different models of mobile devices from. not just iPad and iPhone.

Note that you have to refresh the page each time you change a device emulator. Otherwise it won't load with all the characteristics of the current emulation.